# How to sort a list of lists of strings

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a list of lists of string

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string>();
l1.Add("i");
l1.Add("k");

List<string> l2 = new List<string>();
l2.Add("f");
l2.Add("a");

pChain = new List<List<string>>();
pChain.Add(l1);
pChain.Add(l2);
...
```

I want to sort `pChain` based on the first item of each list (the result should be l2, l1).

I tried `pChain.Sort();` but an exception occurs

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to compare two elements in the array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default call to `pChain.Sort()` can't predict that you want to sort by the first element, you need to explicity specify that:

```
pChain.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.FirstOrDefault(), y.FirstOrDefault()));
```

Alternatively you can use Linq's OrderBy (which is a **stable** sort as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx)):

```
pChain = pChain.OrderBy( x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two
>   elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In
>   contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements
>   that have the same key.

Comment: Thank you this helped me alot

Answer (score 7):

You get that error because C# can't know how to sort an item of `pChain` for you because it is an `IEnumerable` of its own.

Would you want to sort it by the `Max` items? Or by `Count` of items?.. Or many others

You should supply some rule for it to compare by like an `IComparable<List<string>>` or:

```
pChain = pChain.OrderBy(item => item.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Thank you, in the question I requested sorting based on the first item of each list of string.